# Unable to export .p12 from Keychain access

Tags: macos, keychain, p12

I'm facing weird situation. For Apple Push Notification I can't export .p12 file from Keychain access. I can highlight both items and click on Export 2 items but after that nothing happens. All steps are correct as I've been doing it all the time. It seems something is wrong with keychain access or my Mac? I did it successfully few days back for another key and it worked, exporting for this old one doesn't work now. I don't think there is any error or problem in generating certificate otherwise it should work for older keys.

Login is selected in left pane. Any suggestions?

[image: Keychain Access]

Comment: Tried restarting your machine? Are you able to export of certs?

Comment: Lol, yes that was the common sense. Reboot the machine. Works always. Yes it worked now. Tx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebooting machine worked in my case.

Comment: Thx man, made my day. 
I was trying to import a p12 file without password and it was failing with "Wrong password". I noticed that I also have the problem you described, I tried the solution and now it works, I can also import the p12 file.

Comment: This is a terrible answer.

Answer (score 5):

This problem also happens when you happen to have selected the wrong keychain (like if you accidentally had single clicked on the System keychain rather than Login keychain). If the cert signing request came from that machine, it would associate the private key with the Login keychain. So if you somehow then downloaded and imported the certificate into the System keychain, Keychain Access would not find the matching private key and would not put the cert under "My certificates", and cannot export a p12. You might as well have tried importing to the keychain on a different Mac.

So, make sure the import is into the keychain associated with the private key. Often this would be the Login keychain.

Comment: then how do we move it system to login

Comment: @mychar You can drag and drop from system to login. You may need to provide an admin password to proceed, but other than that, it should not be a problem.